# XSLT Transform screws up <br/> tags

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to do an XSLT transform (server side, with php), and I want XHTML as output of that conversion, because it's a part of an XHTML page.
If I use

```
    <xsl:output method="html" />
```

it generates code that is valid html code, but has br tags (without /) so it won't validate as xhtml;

If I use

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
```

here comes the absurdity: the output does have br/ tags, and IS proper xml, but when i put it into the page it belongs to, some closing tags disappear for no apparent reason.

Here's the XSL file http://hbxplayer.sf.net/test/mobile.xsl (it's a bit long for pasting it here)

The PHP that does the transformation is this:

```
    ob_start();
    include 'presetList_xml.php';
    $xml=ob_get_clean();
    $xsl=file_get_contents("mobile.xsl");
    $xslt=new XSLTProcessor();
    $xslt->importStyleSheet(new SimpleXMLElement($xsl));
    echo $xslt->transformToXml(new SimpleXMLElement($xml));
```

The JS that loads the output is this:

```
    function loadPresetList(){
        var listArea=document.getElementById("presetsArea");
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
                if(xmlhttp.status==200||xmlhttp.status==0){
                        listArea.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }else{ //ERROR, TRY AGAIN
                        listArea.innerHTML="Error. Retrying...";
                        loadPresetList();
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","presets_transformer.php?type=mobile&r="+Math.random(),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Nothing too special, as you can see; but it's my first time using XSLT so I may be doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Putting a div around each element seems to fix this problem. Why? I have no idea. Still: the first tag opened always lack the closing tag

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then it usually only supports either output method `html` to generate HTML 4 to be served as `text/html` or output method `xml` to generate XML or XHTML to be served with an XML MIME type like `application/xml` or to be served with the XHTML MIME type `application/xhtml+xml`. However older IE version (including IE 8) don't support XHTML served as `application/xhtml+xml`. And `innerHTML` is known to have problems with XHTML as well, in particular in older browsers.

XSLT 2.0 has an output method `xhtml` to generate well-formed XHTML that can be served as `text/html` and that would be the right option in my view of you want to deal with XHTML to be sent to older browsers.

Given that you use PHP which only supports XSLT 1.0 and the use of `innerHTML` I strongly suggest to have the XSLT stylesheet create HTML 4 or HTML 5 and to avoid XHTML.

Comment: Or generate both: HTML for browser-based rendering, and XHTML for further application processing.